# Active Scaffold + Ruby 2.3.5 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activescaffold

I have an application with Rails 2.3.5. And Im trying to use AS latest version, I have used it previously but cant make it work here.
I have my ingredient_categories Controller, where i put

```
class Administration::IngredientCategoriesController < ApplicationController
layout "default"
    active_scaffold :ingredient_categories 
end
```

I have this set up on routes to be :active_scaffold=>true
I have a model also called ingredient_category, and in the views folder (inside administration/ingredient_categories, and /ingredient_categories) i have nothing as it is usual.

And Im getting over and over again:

Template is missing

Missing template ingredient_categories/list.html in view path themes/aqueouslight:app/views

I had an error before asking me for a list.erb, which I created and put

'ingredient_categories', :label => 'Categorias' %>

And now this error of the list.thml...
Cant make it work! dont know whhy really... whould be SO simple and its burning my head now..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the [render_component plugin](http://github.com/rails/render_component) installed, as it was deprecated from rails 2.3.x and is used by active scaffold

This may not be the cause of your particular problem but you will have trouble with it if you combine AS+Rails2.3.x

I hope it helps

Comment: I already have render component installed and working. But there is no way to make it work. Dont know what else to do. Do you know any other possible solution.